# how to remove sidebar from particular one page

Tags: php, sidebar

I am writing this code in page.php for removing the sidebar in one page

```
<?php if (is_page('x')) : ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

... where `"x"` is the ID of that page.

but I am having a bit of trouble though the forum which is the page in question does not stretch across the whole page. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This would be a CSS issue, where you need to adjust the page width to accommodate the loss of sidebar. Sadly, CSS-only issues are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Try checking if your theme has a full-width [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:page-templates-pulldown-screenshot.png) or similar

Comment: there is no option of my custumpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the page `ID` in `is_page` then you should remove the single inverted commas. Please read the documentation first.
[is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) see the examples section and your issue will be solved.

Comment: where i add this condition,in which page ?

Comment: you can add this condition in your page template where the statement for adding a sidebar is written

Comment: i am used this condition but its also not work,,               <?php endif; ?><?php if (!is_page('portfolio-3')) : get_sidebar(); endif; ?>
                            <div class="<?php if (!is_page('portfolio-3')) : ?>myclass<?php else : ?>myclasswider<?php endif; ?>">

Comment: The code seems to be okay. Isn't this doing what is expected?

Comment: its remove sidebar but all content of page not display  on sidebar space,

Comment: You need to add similar condition to your container as well. Ex. if(is_page('some_page')) `add some full width class here` else {}. You need to handle the content display with the help of CSS.

Comment: sorry i cant get it

Comment: Add a condition to your content wrapper which goes something like `class="<?php if (!is_page('portfolio-3')) : ?>myclass<?php else : ?>myclasswider<?php endif; ?>"`. This will solve the issue.

Comment: but where ?in which page in wordpress

Comment: In the same page where you are adding condition for not displaying the sidebar.

Comment: this is not work yar

Answer (score 0):

This condition is check in page.php

you have check condition 2 times on page.php

First your div like

```
<div class="container <?php if(is_page('x')) { echo 'new_class'}">
```

Here new_class is your full width class which overwrite to container class.

Same as for sidebar do this

Comment: i am used this condition but its also not work,, <?php endif; ?><?php if (!is_page('portfolio-3')) : get_sidebar(); endif; ?> <div class="<?php if (!is_page('portfolio-3')) : ?>myclass<?php else : ?>myclasswider<?php endif; ?>">

Comment: Please Check your slug name. Its right ??
Because its working for me.
I have tried this <div class="<?php if (!is_page('dashbord')) : ?>myclass<?php else : ?>myclasswider<?php endif; ?>">Hello</div>

Comment: this code remove the sidebar but not display all content on all space of page

Comment: You have to change in css like 
.myclass { width : 600px;}
.myclasswider { width : 960px; }

Comment: i have all ready done this but not work,

Comment: Can you send me your link ??